# PHP : How to set timer to every night 12:00am

Tags: php, timer, reset

I have a PHP function that sets the timer for every 24 hours from the current time, and i'm using that function in my website as time() + 24 * 60 * 60 but i want the timer to be reset every night at 12:00am how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Linux/nix, create a [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) that calls your PHP script and runs in a specific hour and time.